# How to refresh a ListView to requery its cursor to repopulate its data and its views

Tags: android

I have a ListView which uses a CursorAdatper as its adapter.
I would like to have the list view to

- requery its data
- refresh its view once the requery is done.

I tried:

```
CursorAdapter adapter = (CursorAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And i tried:

```
CursorAdapter adapter = (CursorAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
adapter.getCursor().requery();
```

but none worked.  I have set a break point in my `ContentProvider`'s query method, but I don't see the requery being called or my ListView getting refreshed with new data.

Can you please tell me what is the solution to my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling `requery()` on a database or content provider `Cursor` attached to `ListView` via a `CursorAdapter` automatically refreshes the list (your second scenario above). You can see [some](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/) [examples](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/ContentProvider/ConstantsPlus/) of this. If that is not working for you, there may be some bug in your `ContentProvider` or adapter.

Comment: it works but how about the performance? requery is easy to use but I don't know if it is good.

Comment: requery is now marked as deprecated and there is even a little note accompanying it in the sdk.  what's the best way to do this now, it is cool to still use requery?

Comment: the android sdk says it's better to just request a new cursor, but how to update the listview after?

Comment: @Ran: Use `changeCursor()` or `swapCursor()` on your `CursorAdapter`

Comment: the only sequence I got to work is adapter.notifyDataSetChanged, followed by adapter.getCursor().requery();
Neither adapter.swapCursor(adapter.getCursor()) nor changeCursor worked. This API clearly misses a simple refresh() that rebuilds the ListView without any questions asked

Comment: Even now in year 2017 (two thousand and seventeen) this is still not resolved. There is still no consistent way to refresh data in adapter.

Answer (score 11):

In the new API (using loader manager) you can use:

```
getLoaderManager().getLoader(_YOUR_LOADER_ID_).forceLoad();
```

Comment: One option is also getLoaderManager().restartLoader();

Comment: @Anderson with `restartLoader` you need to supply the args and callbacks again, `getLoader` is based on the ID only.

Answer (score 5):

you can try: **adapter.changeCursor(new cursor)**. It work for me

Comment: worked for me too. a note to fellow programmers here. this changCursor() need to be called in the UI thread. I got crash when the call is from background thread

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer is probably too late but fyi to others, if you are using a cursor loader (as you probably should do instead), just do

getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

where uri is the same uri used for the cursor loader.