# Notify data change in a cursor without using a ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-cursor, notify

Can i notify a cursor after a new record is inserted in a table without using a ContentProvider?

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544913/android-how-to-use-cursoradapter) - he said that he used the `requery()` method.

And the first answer use a `ContentProvider` - note: I want to use this data only within the application

Any suggestion?

Comment: If your data is not related to db and any change in data of list is done then call notifydatasetchanged() on adapter and the list will be refreshed

Comment: my data is related to db

Comment: You can still use a content provider and maintain the data private to your application by setting `android:exported` to `false` in the provider XML declaration within the manifest.

Comment: Content Providers are useless. They only cover to most basic crud queries and nothing else, there's a lot more to SQL then that.

Comment: Have you considered CursorLoader?  Loaders are supposed to monitor data for modifications.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8320784/257948
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if you're not using content providers and cursorloaders, you have to go old school.  Your DB curser should have a "requery" invoked.  The documentation warns against this expensive code, but that's why they made cursorloaders - to address those issues.