# How to use context menu in listview for android when creating sqlite database and make operation for sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, contextmenu

I created database and Y display record on listview,if i long pressed on listview record then context menu is open. In context menu, there are two operation first,Show operation and second delete operation. If i select show then full record is show in next activity.

**ListActivity.java**

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> items_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    dbhelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int index_id;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        Button btn;
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newProjectlist);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent intent= new Intent(ListActivity.this,NewProject.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });  
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.projectListView);
        setUpList();
        dh = new dbhelper(this);
        Cursor c = getAllData();
        showAllData(c);  
        registerForContextMenu(lv);      
    }

  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        if(v.getId() == R.id.projectList){
            menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Record List");
            menu.add(0,1,menu.NONE,"Delete Record");
            menu.add(0,2,menu.NONE,"Show Record");
        }
    }

    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if(itemId == 1)
        {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
            menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            index_id = menuinfo.position;
            deleteUserData(index_id);
        }
        if(itemId == 2){
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo;
            menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            index_id = menuinfo.position;
            editUserData(index_id);
        }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

    private void editUserData(int indexid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String user_id = items_id.get(indexid);
        Intent intEdit = new Intent(ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intEdit.putExtra("EditID", user_id);
        startActivityForResult(intEdit, 1);
    }

    private void deleteUserData(int indexid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String user_id = items_id.get(indexid);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id " + user_id, 1).show();
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("timer","_ID" + "=" + user_id, null);
        finish();
//      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record deleted successfully", 1).show();
    }

    private void showAllData(Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            String name = c.getString(1);
            String timerpoint1 = c.getString(2);
            String timerpoint2 = c.getString(3);
            String timerpoint3 = c.getString(4);
            String servicetime1 = c.getString(5);
            String servicetime2 = c.getString(6);
            items.add("" + name);
            items_id.add(""+id);
        }
        setUpList();
    }

    private Cursor getAllData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db = dh.getReadableDatabase();
        //String sortorder = dh.Name + "DESC";
    //  String query ="SELECT DISTINCT name FROM timer";
    //  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //   if (c != null) {
    //            c.moveToFirst();
    //        }
        String[] cols = new String[] {dh.Name, "name"};
        Cursor c = db.query(true, "timer",null,null,null,null,"ASC",null, null);   
        //Cursor cur = db.query(Distinct,"timer", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        return c;   
        }
    private void setUpList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
    }   

    }
```

If I select delete then delete the record. Using Context menu we can achive this goal. I have some code for that application but the code is not working properly. So, please help for this.

Comment: how isn't it working properly? does the app crash? there's no visible change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide more details on what you are seeing, however looking at your code i'm guessing that the listview is probably staying in the same state, and not refreshing after you delete.  If that is the case you probably need to [re-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850771/how-to-refresh-a-listview-to-requery-its-cursor-to-repopulate-its-data-and-its-v) your cursor.  This method is deprecated, however you should be able to use it to validate if that is the problem, or just grab a new instance of the cursor and load it as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery) suggest.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things: first your delete method is off. you got the id field then found the corresponding string to delete with, but you're still looking to delete in the `_id` field with this string. Nothing will be deleted this way because these strings wont be in that column. better is to simply delete by the original `long id`.

```
private void deleteUserData(long indexid) {
    db.delete("timer","_ID" + "=" + indexid, null);
    finish();
}
```

that's it. now the other issue is actually retrieving the id to delete with. you're using

```
index_id = menuinfo.position;
```

but that won't give you any id in the database. that's just gives you the position on the `ListView` adapter. you need to use this position, to get this `_id`. Since you're using an `ArrayAdapter` it means getting the `_id` from the corresponding collection used to populate this listview.

So based on your population method.

```
private void showAllData(Cursor c) {
    while(c.moveToNext())
    {
        int id = c.getInt(0);
        String name = c.getString(1);
        .....
        items.add("" + name);
        items_id.add(""+id);
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
}
```

It should be obvious what you need to do now to get this `_id` based on position now.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if(itemId == 1)
        {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuinfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            int position = menuinfo.position;
            String id_string = items_id.get(position);
            long id = Long.valueOf(id_string);
            deleteUserData(id);
//          then you probably want it off the corresponding collection too
            items_id.remove(position);
        }
        .....
```

Comment: i did what i could to make a solution with your code, but i gotta say it is not the most elegant of implementations. for tasks like this, you might want to look into `CursorAdapters` as they can provide `_id` straight to the adapter. moreover, it would only require working with the database, as the sole dataset.

Comment: but context menu is not display when i long press in the listview record. please give me suggestion for context menu to work

Comment: please give me code for context menu for retriving (delete and show) data in android

Comment: my question was if the context menu was displaying before you modified the code to what i've written. try removing the code bracket `if(v.getId() == R.id.projectList){`

Comment: menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   menu.setHeaderTitle("Record List");
   menu.add(0,1,menu.NONE,"Delete Record");
   menu.add(0,2,menu.NONE,"Show Record");